# GET http://127.0.0.1:9989/favicon.ico Not Found

Tags: java, html, web, icons, web-frontend

I have the following error:

```
 favicon.ico:1  -> GET http://127.0.0.1:9989/favic
```

I have read some question answers about the same problem, but I have a problem finding the HTML (?) file to make changes.

Could you please help me? What are the steps I have to follow in order to solve this error on my screen? I can't run my program.

Answer (score 0):

Google favicon generator and make an icon. Name it favicon.ico and drop it in your webroot.

See if this helps.

Also here is a tutorial on favicon: https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon